# Async computation with Validation in Scala using Scalaz

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalaz

Being writing a completely async library to access a remote service (using Play2.0), I'm using `Promise` and `Validation` to create non-blocking call, which has a type presenting fail and valid result at once.

`Promise` comes from Play2-scala, where `Validation` comes from scalaz.

So here is the type of examples of such functions

- f :: `A => Promise[Validation[E, B]]`
- g :: `B => Promise[Validation[E, C]]`

So far, so good, now if I want to compose them, I can simple use the fact that `Promise` present a `flatMap`, so I can do it with a for-comprehension

```
for (
   x <- f(a);
   y <- g(b)
) yield y
```

Ok, I took a shortcut to my problem here because I didn't reused the `Validation` results within the for-comprehension. So if I want to reuse `x` in `g`, here is how I could do

```
for (
   x <- f(a); // x is a Validation
   y <- x.fold(
      fail => Promise.pure(x),
      ok => g(ok)
   )
) yield y
```

Fair enough, but this kind of boilerplate will go to pollute my code over and over again. The problem here is that I've a kind of two-levels Monadic structure like `M[N[_]]`.

At this stage, is there any structure in f° programming that enables working with such structure by skipping easily the secong level:

```
for (
   x <- f(a); //x is a B
   y <- g(b) 
) yield y
```

Now, below is how I achieved something similar.

I created kind of Monadic structure that wraps the two level in one, let say `ValidationPromised` which pimped the `Promise` type with two methods:

```
def /~> [EE >: E, B](f: Validation[E, A] => ValidationPromised[EE, B]): ValidationPromised[EE, B] = 
    promised flatMap { valid => 
        f(valid).promised
    }

def /~~>[EE >: E, B](f: A => ValidationPromised[EE, B]): ValidationPromised[EE, B] = 
    promised flatMap { valid => 
        valid.fold (
            bad => Promise.pure(KO(bad)),
            good => f(good).promised
        )
    }
```

This allows me to do such things

```
      endPoint.service /~~>                                   //get the service
      (svc =>                                                 //the service
        svc.start /~~> (st =>                                 //get the starting elt
          svc.create(None) /~~>                               //svc creates a new elt
          (newE =>                                            //the created one
            newEntry.link(st, newE) /~~>                      //link start and the new
            (lnk => Promise.pure(OK((st, lnk, newE))))        //returns a triple => hackish 
          ) 
        )
      )
```

As we can see `/~~>` is pretty similar to `flatMap` but skips one level. The problem is the verbosity (that's why "for-comprehension" exists in Scala and "do" in Haskell).

Another point, I've the `/~>` that stands like a `map` also but works on the second level (instead of the Valid type -- *third* level)

So my second question is corollary to the former... Am I approching a sustainable solution with this construction ?

*sorry to be that long*

Comment: I've been meaning to use ScalaZ with my Play apps for a while now, and this is a good nudge for me. I'll let you know how I get on, and will hopefully be able to put a meaningful answer here.

Comment: Yeah! Thx. Actually the real problem is not using ScalaZ with Play. It is a more general question (about f° prog), because without Play (so only ScalaZ) I'd used `IO` instead of `Promise`. Hence, I'd have the same pattern, that's to say : `IO[Validation[E, A]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept you are looking for here is [monad transformers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers).  In brief, monad transformers compensate for [monads not composing](http://blog.tmorris.net/monads-do-not-compose/) by allowing you to "stack" them.

You didn't mention the version of Scalaz you are using, but if you look in the [scalaz-seven branch](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven), you'll find [ValidationT](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/ValidationT.scala).  This can be used to wrap any `F[Validation[E, A]]` into a `ValidationT[F, E, A]`, where in your case `F = Promise`.  If you change `f` and `g` to return `ValidationT`, then you can leave your code as

```
for {
  x ← f(a)
  y ← g(b)
} yield y
```

This will give you a `ValidationT[Promise, E, B]` as a result.

Comment: MMmh look the kind of thing I'm looking for !! Ok, so I'll try first with the monad transformer my self, for two reason because it's the only way to learn, and secondly because I'm on the 6.0.4 branch. And then I'll probably move to the 7th, and refactoring for the ValidatorT... In all cases, I'm gonna come back here to tell more. Thanks again

Comment: Ok. Great doc. I looked into the `ValidationT` its `flatMap` method is indeed what I need (and as guessing it's the same as my `/~~>` one). But in order to use it directly, `Promise` needs a TypeClass instance of `Monad`, which it's doens't. So when ScalaZ will come out, I'll implement it to be able to use `ValidationT` directly.